# I get UInt8 Error?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, swift

I was writing an Tic Tac Toe app when this happened? Can someone help?

```
@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
userMessage.hidden = true
if (!plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done != nil)  {
setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player:1)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *isolate* your problem by simplifying the expression? What part causes the problem?

Comment: Its like this, Im new to all kind of programin, I made this app when looking at a tutorial he didn't get the problem but I did, and i did exactly like he did

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `done` is a boolean variable, so this logical expression is wrong:

```
!done != nil
```

I think you meant:

```
!done != false
```

which can be rewritten as

```
done == false
```

or even

```
!done
```